# IsDbExpression from IQueryable implementation articles

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I am following the most excellent series of articles by Matt Warren on how to implement IQueryable. In [part 6](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2007/08/09/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-vi.aspx), we come across a call to `expression.NodeType.IsDbExpression()`...

My question is this: since `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.NodeType` does not seem to contain `IsDbExpression()` method, what could this be a reference to?

Many thanks.

P.S. I've e-mailed the author, so I will publish an update if/when I hear from him - for the benefit of anybody following the same series.

Comment: I bet the author is using the [IQ ToolKit](https://iqtoolkit.codeplex.com/). This toolkit has the method in question and is an extension to LINQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matt does say that he used/modified the IQ Toolkit.  It has the `IsDbExpression` extension method (http://iqtoolkit-oracle.googlecode.com/svn-history/r2/trunk/IQToolkit.Data/Common/Expressions/DbExpressionExtensions.cs)

Comment: Many thanks, Peter! I can now see that Matt introduces IQ Toolkit (which I understand he also wrote) in part 12 of his series (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2008/11/18/linq-links.aspx)... I just didn't get that far! 
Thanks for your answer!